# Visual Studio 2010 compiling inline assembly in c++ as if Visual Studio 6?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, visual-c++-6, visual-c++-2010

I have a C++ project created in VS6 that was opened in VS2010 and compiles fine. It contains a class with a bit of inline assembly including the following code:

```
__asm{
  mov eax,this
  mov esi,[eax].m_pImage
  ...
```

All fine and dandy, until I try and create a new MFC C++ project in VS2010 and add the class with the assembly code shown above. Suddenly, this will not compile as the newer interpretation of __asm requires the code to be as follows (or something similar; this compiles in any case):

```
__asm{
  mov eax,this
  mov esi,[eax]this.m_pImage
  ...
```

Now, for the life of me, I can not figure out what the difference is between the two projects which allows the converted VS6 project to compile the (presumable currently invalid) inline assembly code in VS2010, while a newly created project can't.

Is there somewhere a (hidden) setting which allows one to use the old VS6 compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VS6 inline ASM seems like a bug that was fixed. I say that because I am not sure how the compiler could verify that `m_pImage` was a member of what was loaded in the `eax` register and therefore could not find the offset. To answer your question, there is no way, I am aware of, to use the old ASM semantics in the VS6 compiler.

I would make a local variable outside of the inline ASM and assign that to `esi` instead.

```
void * pointer = this.m_pImage;
__asm
{
   mov ebx, pointer
   mov esi, ebx
   ...
```

Comment: When you convert a project from VS6 (and ONLY VS6 -- this does not happen for other versions) a ton of compatibility settings are applied. It's likely this bugfix was added but the old codepath is still being used in in VS6 compatibility mode.

Comment: And there is no way of replicating these compatibility settings?

Comment: Ignore that last comment... Reading the answer and Billy's comment again, it becomes clear to me that we should not want to have our buggy legacy VS6 code still working in this day and age.